# Can there be more than one template method in an implementation of the Template Method pattern?

Tags: design-patterns, template-method-pattern

Can an abstract class in an implementation of the Template Method pattern have more than one template method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes.** The [Template Method design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) is about allowing derived classes to *implement parts of an algorithm* for which the base class provides the basic structure.

The base class defines *a template method for each portion* of the algorithm that the derived classes would have to implement.